# Solr Sunspot -- How to make 2 strings like "Co." and "Company" appear identical?

Tags: solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I have many records that contain abbreviations in a column of names.  I might have the record "ABC Brewing Co.", and I want solr to interpret this as being identical to a search for "ABC Brewing Company".  Any ideas on how this might be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into using the [SynonymFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.SynonymFilterFactory) at index or query time to accomplish this.